# Python What am I doing wrong, do I def main() for it to work?

Tags: python

I have improved this code a lot and it is almost done, please help me make this function correctly! Do I have to do Def main()For it to move and work?

```
def game_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print("Killer Wolf Text Game")
    print("---" * 20)
    print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be killed by the Wolf.")
    print("---" * 20)
    print('Move Commands: North , South , East , or West.')
    print("---" * 20)
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
    print("---" * 20)


game_instructions()

rooms = {
    "Main fair ground": {'South': 'Food stand', 'North': 'Arcade', 'East': 'Corn field', 'West': 'Candy shop'},
    "Food stand": {'North': 'Main fair ground', 'East': 'Security', 'item': 'Armor'},
    "Arcade": {'South': 'Main fair ground', ' East': 'Gift shop', 'item': 'gloves'},
    "Corn field": {'West': 'Main fair ground', 'North': 'Petting area', 'item': 'Killer Wolf'},
    "Candy shop": {'item': 'candy', 'East': 'Main fair ground'},
    'Security': {'West': 'Food stand', 'item': '1LB of meat'},
    'Gift shop': {'West': 'Arcade', 'item': 'sword'},
    'Petting area': {'South': 'Corn field', 'item': 'wolf repellent'}
}





current_room = 'Main fair ground'  # starts player in the Main fair ground
inventory = []  # Adds an inventory


def get_new_room(current_room, direction):
    rooms = current_room  # declares new room as current room.
    for i in rooms:  # starts loop
        if i == current_room:  # if statement
            if direction in rooms[i]:  # if statement
                rooms = rooms[i][direction]  # Assigns new room.
    return rooms  # returns new room


def get_item(current_room):
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:  # if statement
        return rooms[current_room]['item']  # return statement
    else:
        return 'This room has no item!'  # return statement


while (current_room):  # gameplay loop
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room))  # tells player what room they are in.
    print('Inventory:', inventory)  # shows player their inventory
    item = get_item(current_room)  # defines item as get item
    print('You found the:', item)  # tells the player what item they have found
    if item == 'Killer Wolf':  # if statement
        print('You did not collected all the necessary items to survive! The game has ended!')  # notifies player game has ended.
        break  # ends game
    direction = input('Enter direction you would like to move. >>')  # gets direction from player.
    direction = direction.capitalize()  # Capitalizes the players input to match what is in the dictionary.

    if (direction == 'North' or direction == 'South' or direction == 'East' or direction == 'West'):  # if statement
        new_room = get_new_room(current_room, direction)  # Calling function
        if new_room == current_room:  # if statement
            print('That is a wall not an exit. Try Again!')  # Print statement
        else:
            current_room = new_room  # declares current room as new room
    elif direction == str('get ' + item).capitalize():  # input statement to add item
        if 'item' in inventory:  # if statement
            print('You have already collected this item. Move to another room!')  # print statement
        else:
            inventory.append(item)  # adds item to inventory
    else:
        print('Not a valid direction!')  # Print statement
    if len(inventory) == 6:  # if statement
        print(
            'Congratulations!! You have collected all the necessary items to defeat the killer wolf')  # print statement
```

This is the output I get.

```
Killer Wolf Text Game
------------------------------------------------------------
Collect 6 items to win the game, or be killed by the Wolf.
------------------------------------------------------------
Move Commands: North , South , East , or West.
------------------------------------------------------------
Add to Inventory: get 'item name'
------------------------------------------------------------
You are in the Main fair ground
('Inventory:', [])
('You found the:', 'This room has no item!')
Enter direction you would like to move. >>>? 'South'
That is a wall not an exit. Try Again!
```

> The player should enter a command to either move between rooms or to get an item, if one exists, from a room. The gameplay loop should continue looping, allowing the player to move to different rooms and acquire items until the player has either won or lost the game. Remember that the player wins the game by retrieving all of the items before encountering the room with the Killer Wolf. The player loses the game by moving to the room with the Killer Wolf before collecting all of the items. Be sure to include output to the player for both possible scenarios: winning and losing the game.

Comment: Please post the output you get in the question, so you can properly format it.

Comment: Why when I go south I don’t go to food stand to be able to collect the 1LB of meat item?

Answer (score 2):

In your `get_new_room` function, you introduced a local variable `rooms` that hides the global variable `rooms`, which is the list against which you want to check the `current_room`. So you're always returning the same `current_room`. You should try putting some `print` commands in your code to display the contents of your variables.

Try changing that function to this:

```
def get_new_room(current_room, direction):
    new_room = None
    for i in rooms:  # starts loop
        if i == current_room:  # if statement
            if direction in rooms[i]:  # if statement
                new_room = rooms[i][direction]  # Assigns new room.
    return new_room  # returns new room
```